# Giving DataTables.js elements specific id/class/names

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Just started using [DataTables.js](http://datatables.net/index) the other day and I'm wondering if you can give specific elements on the table custom `id`/`class`/`name` values. For example I've changed the text on the "Search" feature at the top of the table, however now I'd like to give the input box a specific `id`.

[image]

Here is my current attempt.

**jQuery**

```
        $("#thetable").dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Filter results:"
            }
        });

        $.fn.dataTableExt.oJUIClasses["sFilter"] = "my-style-class";
```

**Rendered HTML**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#thetable_filter input').attr('id', 'myId');`